# How to add List item with multiple people picker column using JSOM/Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app, office-365-developer

I want to add list item with multiple people picker column, how can add multiple users in my list column?

I can successfully add **single people picker item**, but not multiple.
My code is working fine with adding single people picker item.

My code:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
        var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, spHostUrl);
        var web = appCtxSite.get_web(); 
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("GNPages");

        var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); 
        var listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);

        var processContri = new Array();
        angular.forEach(ppMultiVal, function (value, key) {
            console.log(value.name);
            processContri.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(value.name));
        });

        listItem.set_item("Title", title);
        listItem.set_item("Description", descr);
        listItem.set_item("ProcessOwner", ppSingleVal.Id);
        listItem.set_item("ProcessContributer", processContri);
        listItem.update();

        ctx.load(listItem);
        //Execute the batch Asynchronously
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, success),
            Function.createDelegate(this, error)
           );
```

Comment: Have you tried a semicolon and pound delimited value in the syntax of userid1;#username1;#userid2;#username2

Comment: processContri.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(value.Name)); Thanks for this post its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this way, and its working fine now with adding single PP field and Multiple PP field to a List...

HEre is my code:

```
        $scope.saveNewPage = function () {
        var title = $scope.newPage.title;
        var descr = $scope.newPage.description; 
        var ppSingleVal = $scope.vm.data.su;
        var ppMultiVal = $scope.vm.data.mu;

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
        var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, spHostUrl);
        var web = appCtxSite.get_web(); 
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("GNPages");

        var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); 
        var listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);

        var processContri = new Array();
        angular.forEach(ppMultiVal.results, function (value, key) {
            console.log(value.Name)
            processContri.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(value.Name));
        });
        console.log(processContri);
        listItem.set_item("Title", title);
        listItem.set_item("Description", descr);
        listItem.set_item("ProcessOwner", ppSingleVal.Id);
        listItem.set_item("ProcessContributer", processContri);
        listItem.update();

        ctx.load(listItem);
        //Execute the batch Asynchronously
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, success),
            Function.createDelegate(this, error)
           );

        function success() {
            console.log('success');
        }

        function error(sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
var revisor = $("#cppRevisor").getUserInfo().Id;
LookupField.set_lookupId(revisor);
newItem.set_item('Revisor', LookupField);

var aprobador = $("#cppAprobador").getUserInfo().Id;
LookupField.set_lookupId(aprobador);
newItem.set_item('Aprobador', LookupField);
```

Where `$("#cppRevisor").getUserInfo().Id` and `$("#cppAprobador").getUserInfo().Id` Is the user's id 
I use [spspeoplepicker.js](https://saikiran78.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/jquery-plugin-sharepoint-2013-client-side-people-picker-control/) to work with peoplepicker.

I hope this helps you.